# Adding outlook rtfbody to a richtextbox including its images

Tags: c#, arrays, richtextbox, outlook-addin

I am making an app that works within outlook. Now I have the following:

```
byte[] rtfMessage = mailItem.RTFBody;
```

I get this byte[] with all the RTF data. This data I want to show in a RichTextBox in a Windows form (C#) including its images.

Can you explain to me how I can show this in a RichTextBox?

Comment: i think i found something

Answer (score 1):

The embedded images are stored as attachments. Outlook inserts them at run-time and replaces the \objattph placeholder tags.

You can try to save the message in the RTF format (`MailItem.SaveAs(..., olRtf)`) and use the generated RTF file.

Answer (score 0):

ok i guess the sollution i wrote under here works.

byte[] rtfmessage = mailItem.RTFBody;

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(rtfmessage, 0, (int)rtfmessage.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        mtest.richTextBox1.LoadFile(ms,    RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

But unfortunately this is not what i want. It looks like the rtfbody of mailitem does not contain the images that are added to the mail. Am i right?

Is there a way to get the body including its images?